# Как сделать расширяющийся лист

Tags: swift3, autolayout

Привет всем!
У меня возник вопрос: у меня view controller, и там находятся данные регистрации. И как сделать так, чтобы при нажатию на строку оттуда вываливается лист с данными этой строки (как бы снизу появляется лист с данными, а строки которые и так были снизу строки на которую нажимаем должны сдвинуться вниз)

Comment: в каком формате у вас это все? tableView?

Comment: Не table view, а view

Comment: Можете пример показать, мне срочно

Comment: то есть вам надо, один вью расширить, остальные сдвинуть, и размер родительского вью увеличить?

Comment: у вас есть вконтакте

Comment: Я хотель фотку отправить

Comment: приложите к вопросу